# CSS :before pseudoelement: vertically centered

Tags: html, css

I've got a label of text and I want to prepend it with an image. The problem is that my text is just of normal size, let's assume it to be `font-size: 12px;`, while the image is a lot bigger, it has `height: 32px;`. When I try to do:

```
<li>
  <span class="download">
    <a href="#abc">download something</a>
  </span>
</li>
```

```css
/* a element CSS */
left: 30px;
margin-left: 30px;

/* a:before pseudoelement CSS */
content: '';
width: 24px;
height: 32px;
position: absolute;
top: 2px;
left: 0px;
background-position: 0 -88px;
```

I get something more or less like this:

```
III text text text
III
III
```

and what I want is something like:

```
III
III text text text
III
```

The problem is that using `:before` the text gets vertically alligned to top and I want it to be vertically centered. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

To vertically center the text set the line height of the text equal to the image height

```
line-height: 32px;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option you could try is using `line-height`.

If you know `li` is going to have a specific height then you can set the `a` tag to have the same `line-height`

```
li {
    height: 50px;
}

li a {
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

This will centre the text to the div.

Then all you need to do is change some more css to have it positioned further from the left (`margin-left` for example) and any other styling you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `line-height` on your parent element (`a`), and set its display as `inline-block` (don't forget the `position: relative` to get your pseudo-element well positioned) :

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

a:before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/24x32);
  width: 24px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <span class="download">
    <a href="#abc">download something</a>
  </span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Remove positioning from the pseudo element.

2) Set `vertical-align: middle;` on the pseudo element

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/z8n45xmz/2/)**

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
a {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
a:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 32px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/24x32);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="download">
    <a href="#abc">download something</a>
  </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

used `display:table` for parent and `display:table-cell` for children